SFDX:Retrieve source in Manifest from Org - Unable to load components
Following output is being displayed while authorizing and trying to retrieve sources from Org from VS code editor using SFDX:Retrieve source in Manifest from Org

3:31:28.131 sf org:login:web --alias DemoDevOrg --instance-url https://login.salesforce.com --set-default
Warning: Ignoring extra certs from C:\Program Files\sf\bin, load failed: error:80000005:system library::Input/output error
Successfully authorized sushanth@happy.com with org ID 00DNS000004AQDR2A4
23:32:26.207 sf org:login:web --alias DemoDevOrg --instance-url https://login.salesforce.com --set-default
ended with exit code 0


23:33:18.767 Starting SFDX: Retrieve This Source from Org


23:33:20.637 ended SFDX: Retrieve This Source from Org

Spent almost 6 hours rolling back and installing the components, setting environment variables but was not successful. Highly appreciate if anyone can guide me on how to resolve the issue.

Do I understand correctly any metadata download fails with this message, downloading nothing? Do other commands work? Did you install sf via npm or with an exe file? (Hopefully not somehow both ways, which could maybe result in such problems.) What happens when you execute from the cli? Same thing? There's quite some advice to be found searching for 'error:80000005:system'...
